# Netcat Triggers Connection Reset Error When Program Exits

Tags: bash, networking, netcat

I'm using `netcat -e $prog`, which is fine, but whenever `$prog` exits, `netcat` hangs up on the original connection. Any thoughts on how to make it disconnect with a clean FIN-ACK? Or why it's not in the first place?

```
$ nc localhost 2000

*random data that should just cause it to exit cleanly*

read(net): Connection reset by peer

$
```

Comment: Does your program exit with a `0` exit status code?